# Command manager procedure in MicroStrategy not converting to date

Tags: java, microstrategy

I am running below command manager procedure in Microstrategy but it does not convert the string into date, tried lot of options. Can someone please assist?

```
*********** PROCEDURE***************************************

String sQuery = "LIST ALL SUBSCRIPTIONS FOR SCHEDULE \"" + sScheduleName + "\" FOR PROJECT \"" + projectName + "\";";
ResultSet oSubs=executeCapture(sQuery);
oSubs.moveFirst();

while(!oSubs.isEof()){
String sSubsName = oSubs.getFieldValueString(DisplayPropertyEnum.GUID);
ResultSet RecList = executeCapture("LIST ALL PROPERTIES FOR SUBSCRIPTION GUID " +sSubsName+ " FOR PROJECT \"projectname\";");
RecList.moveFirst();
while(!RecList.isEof()){
ResultSet oResultSetSubProps = (ResultSet)RecList.getResultCell(SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_SET).getValue();
oResultSetSubProps.moveFirst();
while(!oResultSetSubProps.isEof())
{
String d1 = oResultSetSubProps.getFieldValueString(DisplayPropertyEnum.EXPIRATIONDATE);

// the below few lines in red return nothing, its unable to convert to Date as it is unable to recognize the Expiration date in the String format.


java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
String dateInString = d1;
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
printOut(formatter.format(date));


oResultSetSubProps.moveNext();
}
RecList.moveNext();
}
oSubs.moveNext();
}
```

Comment: I am getting Unparseable date: "" though i am entering in correct format of  M/dd/yyyy format

Comment: What version of MicroStrategy are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.4. I was able to figure out though. Thanks for checking in.

Comment: No problem. I tried your code on 10.4 and worked like a charm... what was the issue?

Comment: For some reason the string was neither empty or null or blank. I had to use the string length to successfully parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. The string was neither empty, nor null and no even blank but it would still not parse it so i had to use the length of the string.

```
java.text.DateFormat formatter = new    java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy",Locale.US);
     String dateInString = d1;
    if(d1.trim().length()>0)
    {
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    if(todaydate.compareTo(date)>0)
    {
    printOut(name+";"+formatter.format(date));
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(d1.contains("/"))
{
    Date EDate=new Date(d1);  
    Date today= new Date();
    if(d1.compareTo(today)<0)
    {
    printOut("Expired");
    }
}
else
{
printOut("Active");
}
```

//blank or null values can be handled in Else condition instead.. Hope it helps..

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.